# Novice at Java trying to get first code sample running

Tags: java, syntax

I'm trying to get this code snippet running:

```
public static void findNeedles(String haystack, String[] needles){
    if(needles.length > 5){
        System.err.println("Too many words!");
    } else {
        int[] countArray = new int[needles.length];
        for(int i = 0; i < needles.length;++){
            String[] words = haystack.split("[\"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
            for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
                if(words[j].compareTo(needles[i]) == 0){
                    countArray[i]++;
                }
            }
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < needles.length; j++){
            System.out.println(needles[j] + ": " + countArray[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Know I'm supposed to wrap this in `"public static void main(String[] args) {"`

but can't get the syntax right.

Anyone help a novice get started?

Comment: Just create the `main` method which you know about and call your own method from there with the suitable arguments.

Comment: Hi MJB, welcome to SO. You will need to spend more energy on your question.

Comment: add `public static void main(String[] args){ String haystack = ...; String[] needles = ...; findNeedles(haystack, needles); }` to create a main method. You can also call specific functions without needing a main

Comment: @MJB - Don't get discourage by the down votes and read the help section of stackoverflow so you learn how to write good questions and answers. Cheers.

Comment: I edited my answer to highlight the syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use an IDE like Spring Tool Suite, Eclipse IDE or InteliJ.
They will highlight syntax errors and give you a hint of what the problem may be.

You forgot to reference the variable `i` in the first `for` loop when telling what to do with the variable after each loop. You have `; ++` and it should be `; i++`

So to call your method from main you could do something like this:

```
public class YourClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] needles = new String[2];
        findNeedles("some string", needles);
    }

    public static void findNeedles(String haystack, String[] needles){
        if(needles.length > 5){
            System.err.println("Too many words!");
        } else {
            int[] countArray = new int[needles.length];
            for(int i = 0; i < needles.length; i++){
                String[] words = haystack.split("[\"\'\t\n\b\f\r]", 0);
                for(int j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
                   if(words[j].compareTo(needles[i]) == 0){
                        countArray[i]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for(int j = 0; j < needles.length; j++){
                System.out.println(needles[j] + ": " + countArray[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To tell the truth, your question is not kind of java's syntax. I mean, this is commonsense in java.(sorry if I seemed rude or abrupt on account of my poor English)

Please find it.
https://www.journaldev.com/12552/public-static-void-main-string-args-java-main-method
I wish it helps you.

Comment: @MJB Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I recommend f-CJ's answer. I think it is best and he is very kind person :)